# Browser Word Document Editor

Tags: ms-word, webbrowser-control, inline-editing

I've been looking at Adobe Buzzword and Zoho Writer and the functionality their editor controls provide is something that I need to incorporate into an application I'm working on.

To be clear, I'm not looking for a WYSIWYG HTML editor like FCKEditor or the Telerik R.A.D controls editor.

What I'm looking for is an editor that can create, edit and save word documents to the server within the browser.

Does anyone know of any controls (commercial or open source) that are available that might be able to provide this functionality? I'd prefer DHTML based, but Flash or Silverlight would be ok too, it just needs to live inside the browser.